# div in bottom-center without scrolling

Tags: html, css, video, responsive-design

I want to create a static page with a YouTube video with no content at all. I need the video div at the `center-bottom` of the page without scrolling and without the height and width mentioned (because I am using responsive CSS). I tried the following code:

HTML:

```html
<div class="video-content">
  <div class="video-container"><iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/fMJ21v7mX7U" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.video-content {
  width: 45%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.video-container {
  height: 315px;
  background: #666;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 40px;
  width: 45%;
}
.video-container iframe,
.video-container object,
.video-container embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: set video-container css bottom to 0px

Comment: footer height is 40px, so that i give bottom:40px;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `.video-container` width to `100%`. Now to the bottom-center align the video, remove the `position:absolute` for `.video-container iframe`, and add the below CSS:

```css
.video-container iframe {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

To set the video to the bottom of the page set `bottom:0` to `.video-container`

Comment: the video size is automatically increase to page width, but not a actual width

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`!important`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/important) with the height and width of the `video-container` to override your height and width to the height and width of the iframe.

```css
.video-container iframe,
.video-container object,
.video-container embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important; 
}
```